# Hide/Show DD Elements in a Definition List

Tags: jquery, list, show-hide

I haven't been able to figure out (or find) a solution for the following scenario:

We have a `dl` like so:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Term</dt>
        <dd>Item 1</dd>
        <dd>Item 2</dd>
        <dd>Item 3</dd>
        <dd>Item 4</dd>
        <dd>Item 5</dd>
    <dt>Term</dt>
        <dd>Item 1</dd>
        <dd>Item 2</dd>
        <dd>Item 3</dd>
        <dd>Item 4</dd>
        <dd>Item 5</dd>
</dl>
```

We need to hide all `dds` after the first 3 for each `dt` group and show a "view more" link that will toggle visibility on the remaining.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Surely you've tried something. Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help.  This is what we ended up going with:

```
$(function(){
    $("dt").each(function(){
        var $dd = $(this).nextUntil("dt");
        if ($dd.length > 3 && $('input:checked', $dd).length < 1) {
            $dd.filter(":gt(2)").hide();
            $dd.last().after($("<dd class='t'>View More</dd>").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).text($(this).text() == "View More"?"Hide More":"View More").prevAll("dt:first").nextUntil("dt").filter(":gt(2):not('dd.t')").toggle()
            }).css({'cursor':'pointer', 'color':'#0000FF'}));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to do this, but this is what I came up with first. It finds the `dt` elements within the `dl`, then loops through them and hides all elements after the first 3 until the next `dt`:

```
$("dl").find("dt").each(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $(this).nextUntil("dt").filter(function() {
       return count++ > 2;
    }).hide();
    $(this).append(" <a href='#' class='showMore'>See more</a>");
});
$(".showMore").live("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("dl").find("dt").each(function() {
       $(this).nextUntil("dt").show();
       //As suggested by comments, you may want to hide the 'Show more' link now:
       $(this).remove();
    }); 
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sxqFa/2/).

Comment: Having a link that only shows (and no link to hide) is a valid way of doing it and I've seen it on many websites. I think it should just remove (or hide) the "view more" link after it shows the elements, though, otherwise a user might click on it expecting it to hide.

Comment: @Ben - Agreed, that could be a nice feature. I've added it in (see comment in code).

Comment: I just noticed that yours shows all of the hidden dt links. It ought to just show them for the `dt` group. Also the `$(this).remove()` doesn't hide the <a> link, because it's the wrong `this`. Finally, you used closest but I used parent. I should have used closest, though!

I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KmxHh/1/ and I'm going to change mine to `closest` rather than `parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're deep inside of the `<dl>`, I would insert a new `<dd>` element that contains the "view more" link after the last `<dd>` tag, and give it a class to distinguish it from the `<dd>` tags that contain the actual data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('dt').each(function() {
    var sel = $(this), dd = sel.nextUntil('dt');
    if (dd.length > 3) {
      dd.slice(3).addClass('more hidden');
      dd.slice(dd.length-1).after('<dd class="viewMore"><a href="javascript:void(0)">view more</a></dd>');
    }
  });
  $('dl').delegate('dd.viewMore a', 'click', function() {
    $(this).closest('dd').prevUntil('dt').filter('.more').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

Just make sure you have something like this in your css:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Edit: I fixed it. [Here's the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/8h6t8/2/)

Comment: Oops. I should have tried running my code. Working on a revision.

Comment: See my answer, feel free to branch my fiddle and play around with that. There may well be a better way. It would be alot easier if `dd` elements did go inside the `dt`!

Comment: Thanks a lot, James! I fixed mine. I don't think my code is any better, but I think having the "view more" link at the end of each `dt` group is better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   $("dt").each(function(){
     var $dd = $(this).nextUntil("dt"), $this;
     $dd.filter(":gt(2)").hide();
     if($dd.length > 3){  
       $dd.last().after($("<a href='#'>View More</a>").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).text($(this).text() == "View More"?"Hide More":"View More")
          .prevAll("dt:first").nextUntil("dt").filter(":gt(2):not('a')").toggle()
        }));
     }  
   });
});
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sxqFa/5/)

Comment: My bad, I thought dd's are inside dt.

Comment: It would be much easier if they were! See my answer, although there may be a better way to do it, feel free to branch the fiddle and play around with it!

Comment: @All _ Please check my edited answer, it is perfectly working as expected. I have created the fiddle also http://jsfiddle.net/sxqFa/3/

Comment: Nice. Just need a conditional to not add "View More" unnecessarily. (if there are 3 or fewer dd in a cluster). ------- Also, I prefer the View Mores be `span` or `dd`, since they're not really links ------ http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/QJefK/

Answer (score 1):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/APB6F/. This solution gives you the option of toggling the Show/Hide functionality.

```
$("dl").find("dt").each(function(k,v){
    var dtObj = $(this);
    dtObj.nextUntil("dt").filter(function(index){
        if(index > 2){ $(this).hide(); }
    });
    dtObj.append("<a href='#' class='view-more'>Show More</a>");
});

$(".view-more").live('click', function(){
    var mObj = $(this); 
    if(mObj.text() == "Show More"){
        mObj.closest("dt").each(function(k,v){
            var dObj = $(this);
            dObj.nextUntil("dt").filter(function(index){
                $(this).show();
            });        
        });
        mObj.text("Hide More");
    }else{
        mObj.closest("dt").each(function(k,v){
            var dObj = $(this);            
            dObj.nextUntil("dt").filter(function(index){
                if(index > 2){ $(this).hide(); }
            });        
        });
        mObj.text("Show More");
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work. The OP needs to hide everything but the first 3 `dd` elements in each group following a `dt` element. This will hide all of them but the first 3, regardless of `dt` elements.

Comment: I guess you read better than I do :) Updated to meet requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`$('dd:nth-child(n+4)')`

This should select everything but the first 3 dds. This helps: http://leaverou.me/demos/nth.html